# pip uninstall - what is getting deleted?

Tags: python, pip, wildcard, delete-file, biopython

I have a pipeline using biopython.  I installed a different software that also uses biopython, and it overwrote my existing biopython version to give me the latest version.  Some bits of my pipeline now no longer work, I suspect because they use deprecated elements of the earlier biopython pipeline that are no longer useable.

I would therefore like to uninstall biopython and reinstall an earlier version.

When I do `pip uninstall biopython`, this comes up in my command prompt:

```
C:\Users\u03132tk>pip uninstall biopython
Uninstalling biopython-1.79:
  Would remove:
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\*
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\biopython-1.79.dist-info\*
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\biosql\*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\profiler.py
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\~aps\__init__.py
.....many more paths
```

As I understand, `*` is a wild card.  Wouldn't removing `c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\*` (first removed path) remove all of the paths under `Would not remove` that are prefixed with `c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio`?

I'm just trying to clarify what it's doing.

Cheers for reading!

Comment: Did you always install biopython with `pip` or was it previously installed using `conda`?

Comment: In all honesty I can't remember, but I always use pip unless it literally wont work (so I'm fairly confident it was pip)

Answer (score 0):

```
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\profiler.py
    c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\~aps\__init__.py
```

These files are not part of a standard `biopython` installation. `~aps` looks odd. Possibly a previous installation was killed half-way and now your biopython installation is broken?

That being said, you are right that `c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\*` would include `c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bio\profiler.py`. The output is a little confusing here. All files listed under  `Would not remove (might be manually added):` will be kept. Note however that for a clean biopython installation there would be no such entries:

```
(py39) C:\>pip install biopython
Collecting biopython
  Using cached biopython-1.79-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.3 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.23.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy, biopython
Successfully installed biopython-1.79 numpy-1.23.2

(py39) C:\>pip uninstall biopython
Found existing installation: biopython 1.79
Uninstalling biopython-1.79:
  Would remove:
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bio\*
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\biopython-1.79.dist-info\*
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\biosql\*
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled biopython-1.79

(py39) C:\>
```

So I would suggest that after uninstalling, you just remove all remaining files in the `BIO` folder.

**Proof that they are kept**

One can reproduce the message you get by just adding a custom file in the `BIO` folder after installation:

```
(py39) C:\>pip install biopython
Collecting biopython
  Using cached biopython-1.79-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages (from biopython) (1.23.2)
Installing collected packages: biopython
Successfully installed biopython-1.79

(py39) C:\>type nul >> C:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\Bio\profile.py

(py39) C:\>pip uninstall biopython
Found existing installation: biopython 1.79
Uninstalling biopython-1.79:
  Would remove:
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bio\*
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\biopython-1.79.dist-info\*
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\biosql\*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bio\profile.py
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled biopython-1.79

(py39) C:\>dir c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bio
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F060-053A

 Directory of c:\miniconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\bio

18/08/2022  15:16    <DIR>          .
18/08/2022  15:16    <DIR>          ..
18/08/2022  15:16                 0 profile.py
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  35.953.205.248 bytes free

(py39) C:\>
```

**Side Note**

`biopython` is part of the anaconda distribution, so using `pip install` in the base env will have overwritten a package installed via `conda` using `pip`, which is bad practice and can cause inconsistencies in your environment. I would suggest modifying an anaconda base env as little as possible. Instead, you could create an environment that holds all the packages that you need for your pipeline to run stably. You can even have a `.yml` file specifying the required package versions so that you can easily recreate it. This has the advantage that if your experiments lead you to a broken state, you can just recreate the environment (which is a lot more of a pain for the anaconda base with >600 packages)